# Angular 5 router, all children redirected to the default route

Tags: angular, angular-router

My Angular 5 routes contain an error; I cannot figure out what. See below:

- by default, unauthenticated users are shown the login box
- user with a token in localstorage are auto redirected to /secure
- /secure uses pathMatch "full" to redirect to its /dashboard child.

So far all works fine.
Now, I directly set the url of my browser to /secure/admin/users. I expect to see the user admin page. I'm however redirected as per the "redirectTo" statement (dashboard in this case).

Is there anything obviously wrong in my routes? Thanks in advance.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [


  { path: '', component: LoginComponent,
    data: { },
    canActivate: [AuthAutoRedirectService]
  },

  { path: 'secure', component: WrapperComponent,
    data: { },
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],

    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard'},
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: {}, canActivate: [] },

      { path: 'admin', data: { roles: [] }, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], children: [
        { path: 'users', data: {}, canActivate: [], children: [
          { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: AdminUserComponent },
          { path: 'add-user', component: AddUserComponent }
        ]},
      ]}
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Are you using a server like Express or running with `ng serve`? When I run my applications with Express, it redirects all manually set URLs to `index.html` and the applications redirect by itself to respective paths.

Comment: Hi @PedroArantes, I use ng serve. Would that be an issue?

Comment: No, it is not. I'm trying to figure out your problem but I cannot wonder what could be. I was thinking about `AuthGuardService`, but if it was blocking `/secure/admin/users`, it'd block `/secure/dashboard` too (you may try to remove `AuthGuardService` and check if it works). Don't you have any router.navigate(['/secure/dashboard']) in your files?

Comment: Enable route tracing  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {enableTracing: true}) then check the log. May look at path mathching.

Comment: Hi @PedroArantes - indeed, there was a router.navigate left in the wrong place. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Hi @nayakam, thanks for the tip. Helpful option.